# operating on two numpy arrays of different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

suppose i have 2 numpy arrays as follows:

```
init = 100
a = np.append(init, np.zeros(5))
b = np.random.randn(5)
```

so a is of shape (6,) and b is of shape(5,). i would like to add (or perform some other operation, e.g. exponentiation) these together to obtain a new numpy array of shape (6,) whose first value of a (100) is the same and the remaining values are added together (in this case this will just look like appending 100 to b, but that is because it is a toy example initialized with zeroes. attempting to add as is, will produce:

```
a+b
```

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (5,)

is there a one-liner way to use broadcasting, or newaxis here to trick numpy into treating them as compatible shapes?

the desired output:

array([ 100.        ,    1.93947328,    0.12075821,    1.65319123,
         -0.29222052,   -1.04465838])

Comment: Could you do `numpy.random.seed(0)` at the top and re run your code and re print your desired output? Because `np.random` created random values. And your random values will be different from when I call `np.random` from my console.

Comment: Could you tell me if my answer gives you your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

You mean you want to do something like this

```
np.append(a[0:1], a[1:,] + b)
```

What do you want your desired output to be? The answer I've provided performs this brodcast add excluding row 1 from `a`

Comment: this works, but perhaps this is sufficient: np.append(a[0], a[1:] + b)

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept if my solution works.. Yeah they basically do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Not a one-liner but two short lines:

```
c = a.copy()
c[1:] += b
```